# WJXBFS in MicroStrategy Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, teradata, microstrategy

I guess this might not be a real programming question but I cannot imagine I can find the answer anywhere else.

I came across the alias `WJXBFS` all the time whenever I work with SQL in Microstrategy, Oracle and Teradata...

Can anyone share with me what is it short for? (Someone mentioned to me it is the abbreviations of the initials for some of the developers..who are they if that is the case).

Comment: I have been working with Oracle for over 20 years now and I never came across the alias `WJXBFS`

Comment: WJXBFS (fun fact: these are the initials of some of the original SQL Engine developers). Taken from here: http://www.bryanbrandow.com/2011/12/vldb-properties.html

Comment: WJXBFS it's always SQL generated by MicroStrategy, and the initials of two of the developers, I've been told, too :-)  I hate it, especially because those stupid aliases are always renamed in the next nesting level (e.g. WJXBFS2 AS WJXBFS8), making the query unreadable...

Comment: @dnoeth I guess what I want is who are those developers, what are they short for. Do you happen to know?

Comment: this doesn't look like a technical question to me, but you can try to open a case with MicroStrategy support

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is about the reason behind an acronym used by the MicroStrategy SQL Engine as alias for the columns generated during intermediate queries: it could be foo, i_like_ike or stackoverflowAndBeer, it won't change anything

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if giving correct answer but on base of descriptions in [this book](https://books.google.com.sg/books?id=5pNTAgAAQBAJ)) it's a **Metric Column Alias**

> By default the alias generated for a fact column in a report SQL is
>   `WJXBFS` where n is a number. The first metric alias is MicroStrategy
>   engine creates for a report is `WJXBFS1` the next `WJXBFS2`, and so
>   forth.

[this link](http://community.microstrategy.com/t5/Architect/TN44433-How-to-modify-the-column-alias-for-a-metric-in/ta-p/194195) may be related also.

Comment: I guess what I want is who are those developers, what are they short for. Do you happen to know? I will absolutely accept your answer if you tell me who are they?

Comment: @B.Mr.W. I don't know, but they didn't do good thing, instead of it they could choose a more meaningful name for the alias, anyway I'm SORRY for my answer is not answering your question(what is it short for?). however it's relevant a little.

Answer (score 0):

you can change a VLDB setting to get the alias names to be more descriptive and use the metric name. db instance vldb -> metrics -> default to metric name